# how to set apache2 for CodeIgniter ono ubuntu

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu

I have a problem with my codeigniter on ubuntu, every time I use form_open, the problem is like this:

when I have a url like this
http: // localhost / mywebsite
when I submit it will be like this:
http: // localhost / mywebsite / localhost / mywebsite / auth

but when I run it in Windows url it should be:
http: // localhost / mywebsite / auth

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `config.php` under `application/config/config.php`, you need to change two configs there, setting your `base_url` and deleting the `index_page` value:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'your_base_url';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Then in you `FCPATH` create a `.htaccess` file with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now everything should work just fine (if you configured your `lamp` stack correctly cause if not, in this case your need to do some extra steps in your `apache` configurations).